# Understanding bash script if construct having -p on it?

Tags: bash, shell

what this statement is doing in bash?

```
if [ ! -p "$output" ]; then
```

As far as I could understand `!` is a not operator, `"$output"` is an variable but what `-p` signifies here?

Is it a read operation on `"$output"`?

Comment: `man bash` `/CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` : `-p file
              True if file exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).
`

Comment: It helps to know what `[` is. It's not shell syntax or part of `if` -- it's a command (the same command also found under the name `test`), and `-p` is an argument to that command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  How is it duplicate where `-p` syntax is mentioned in these questions? 1 - How to find the options in if conditions of shell [duplicate]? , 2 - List of 'if' switches anywhere?

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat, it's duplicate because it's a strict subset. The other questions ask about *all* the options, and their answers tell you how to get documentation for *all* the options, `-p` included. If we had a different question and answer for every single possible `test` option (`-g`, `-h`, `-L`, `-s`, `-S`, etc), that would be over 25 extra questions, adding no value over just telling people -- once -- to run `help test` (or `help [`) and read what it spits out, which is a description of *every* possible operand.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ ! -p "$output" ]; then
```

It is checking if `"$output"` is not a named pipe.

You can check `help test` for all the string/file/pipe checks.

```
-p FILE        True if file is a named pipe.
```

In `bash` it is better and more efficient to replace `[...]` with `[[...]]` as `[` is an external command and `[[...]]` is internal construct.